# VPN To Provide A Static IP Address

Tags: vpn, static-ip, whitelist

We are developing on a server with a client whose network does not have a VPN and restricts access to the server by a whitelist IP list. Many of our team members do not have static IP addresses as they are fairly mobile and many are working from their homes that do not have an ISP that will provide them with a static IP address.

I was thinking there may be a way for us to connect through a VPN and I was wondering if anyone had a recommendation for a VPN service that would allow our team members to connect to that would in turn have a dedicated IP address that we could put on the server's IP whitelist thus allowing access.

We looked into something like Hamachi but were not sure if that would be the most secure solution as it, to my understanding, would need to be running on the server as well as on each team member's PC.

I've also looked into several online VPN services but they seem mostly geared toward individuals who want to browse the web and hide their IP. Thank you for any suggestions and solutions to our problem.

Comment: [This type of question is off-topic](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), and in any event, you've not provided enough information to make an answerable question.  Most big vendors provide native VPN solutions, however, and there's always OpenVPN if you don't already have something in your environment that suits your needs.

Comment: Do I get this right, you are simultaneously talking about "a whitelist IP list" and "the most secure solution"? Seriously?

Comment: Since you're going to bill the client for having to set up this VPN, you may as well set it up _for_ the client and leave it there when you're done.

Comment: Sorry for being off topic. I suppose I am looking for a proxy service that we can connect to rather than a VPN. The client's internal network is very strict and they do not give us the ability to add or change anything. I agree @HaukeLaging that the security is not the best but unfortunately we have to work around their configuration. Since I suppose I am going down the wrong with referring to a VPN is there another solution that would allow us to obtain a static IP? My goal here is to find a work around for the situation we've been given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A VPN will join you to the network that hosts it.  This means that you can then be part of the internal network and bypass needing a whitelist for the server.  Having an in-house VPN would probably be the best option, and as HopelessN00b put it, most big vendors will have a VPN appliance.

That said, with what you're asking for (ie, a single external IP), it sounds like you're looking for a proxy or gateway.  There's a lot of proxies available.  I don't personally use them, so I can't recommend any good services.  However, how secure these are is something else entirely.  There may be some business-oriented proxies that can give you a secured IP, but again I haven't used them.

Comment: thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I was thinking that a VPN was the right way to go but I will now look for some proxy services.

Answer (score 0):

Just take ANY system, install e.g. OpenVPN, do SNAT, limit the outgoing traffic to the target to forwarded traffic coming from the VPNs and whitelist the SNAT IP.